# Adding elements to a list in Python 3.3 by extracting consecutive elements from two other lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is only my second day of learning Python 3.3 so I admit I have a lot to learn.

In short, I have two lists: List1 is full of odd numbers, List2 is full of even numbers. They are the same length (each has five numbers).

I want to create List4 that contains [1,2,3,4,5,6,…] by combining each element of List1 with the same element from List2, and incrementing a counter. I guessed to use Append. My problem lies by the comment near the end.

I have many more functions to learn about, but I would be most grateful if someone could assist.
My program can no doubt be made slicker, but that can come later.

Thank you!

```
# Fill list with odd numbers up to 10
a = -1
list1 = []
while a < 10:
    a += 2
    print (a)
    list1.append(a)
print ("a = ", a, "\nList 1 = ", list1)

# Fill list with even numbers up to 10
a = 0
list2 = []
while a < 10:
    a += 2
    print (a)
    list2.append(a)
print ("a = ", a, "\nList2 = ", list2)

#Combine the lists side by side
list3 = []
list3 = list1 + list2
print ('List 3 = ', list3)

#Now combine them in numerical order
list4 = []
for i in range (len(list1)):
    list4.append(list1[i] + list2[i]) #Here is the problem
    print (list4) #Here the List4 is gradually filled up
    i += 1
print ("List4 = ", list4)
```

Comment: You don't have to increment i the `for` loop will do that for you. You are also adding the 2 list indices. `list4.append(list1[i] + list2[i])` is the same as `list4.append(1 +2)` or `list4.append(3)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few options:

- Append each item separately:

  ```
  for i in range(len(list1)):
      list4.append(list1[i])
      list4.append(list2[i])
  ```
- Use `list4.extend()` with a list or tuple:

  ```
  for i in range(len(list1)):
      list4.extend([list1[i], list2[i]])
  ```

The previous methods are most similar to your current approach, however I would probably use `zip()` with one of the following methods:

- Using a list comprehension:

  ```
  list4 = [x for t in zip(list1, list2) for x in t]
  ```
- Using a loop:

  ```
  list4 = []
  for t in zip(list1, list2):
      list4.extend(t)
  ```

As a side note, your current code has some oddities.  First of all to create a list of odd or even numbers up to and including 10 you can use `range()` instead of a loop, for example:

```
list1 = list(range(1, 11, 2))
list2 = list(range(2, 11, 2))
```

You also don't need to be manually incrementing `i` within the for loop at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much F.J.

Bullet points 1 and 2 worked fine, but gave a "List index out of range" error - why?

Bullet points 3 and 4 are beyond me (only on day 2) so I will look these up.

My way of building up the lists is probably a throwback to my Pascal days - I didn't know about the range function.

Thank you again!

Comment: You are getting a list index out of range because their is a bug in how you are currently setting up `list1` (it includes 11, so it has one more element than `list2`).  You can fix this by using `a = 1` before the loop, and moving the `a += 2` so that it is the last line inside of the loop, or you can just use my approach, `list1 = list(range(1, 11, 2))`.

Comment: Got it! I changed line 4 to read:
    while a < 9:
and it all works fine. Now I need to smarten up the coding style.
Thank you again - much appreciated from a newbie.

Comment: The list comprehension with `zip` is very, very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehensions:

```
evens = [i for i in range(1,11) if i % 2 == 0]
odds = [i for i in range(1,11) if i % 2 != 0]
both = []
both.extend(evens)
both.extend(odds)
both.sort()

print(both)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ian. That is really quite different to FJ's answer above. It goes to show how useful the range function is.
Much appreciated